# Why does the reverse of Existential Generalisation not hold?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, predicate-logic

This question was prompted by this one: [If $\Delta \vDash \exists x.p(x)$, then $\Delta \vDash p(\tau)$ for some ground term $\tau$. Why is this false?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4625144/if-delta-vdash-exists-x-px-then-delta-vdash-p-tau-for-some-ground), but is a proof-theoretic inquiry into why does the reverse of *Existential Generalisation* not hold (which I have the intuitive feeling is related to the statement below).

The statement in the aforementioned question was as follows:

> If $\Delta \vDash \exists x.p(x)$, then $\Delta \vDash p(\tau)$ for some ground term $\tau$.

I didn't quite get the answers given because I am not well versed in model theory or anything beyond standard n-order logic. I get why a specific *p(a)* or *p(b)* or whatever is not entailed, but why is it that no ground term *p(τ)* is entailed? And, given that many have pointed out that no ground term is entailed in the special case there is no ground term at all, why does the entailment hold in case where we have universal quantification instead?

Comment: See answer: "Structures can have elements which are not named by ground terms. "

Comment: Do you know what a [*ground term*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ground_expression) is? "A ground term of a formal system is a term that does not contain any variables. "

Comment: The issue is that IF the language has no *constant*, there are NO ground terms.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the reply, Mauro. Yes, I do know what a *ground term* is (although I do not know what a structure is, strictly and mathematically speaking). But, still, if the language has *no constant* as you say, how come this > If $\Delta \vDash \forall x.p(x)$, then $\Delta \vDash p(\tau)$ for some ground term $\tau$ < (the universal instantiation) hold?

Comment: It this case: for **all** terms.

Comment: But there are no *ground terms*, as in the existential case; why should this be any different? As you said, there could be NO ground terms, so why infer this for universal quantification?

Comment: It holds for **all** terms; if there are no ground ones, it still holds.